# Select rows based on MAX values of a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running into a slight problem in Oracle SQL.

I have a table that has the following columns
(ID, AttributeID, AttributeValue, Version).

I would like to query the table for the latest version given an attribute id.

For example, if I have the following data

```
ID AttrId AttrValue Version
1  1      A         1 
1  1      B         2 
1  1      C         3
2  1      F         1
2  2      G         1
```

If I decided to filter by attribute id 1, I would like to get

```
ID AttrId AttrValue Version
1  1      C         3
2  1      F         1
```

The query will be very simple if I supply the id, because I can filter first
by the ID and AttributeID, and then find the max for the version column.

However, I am still looking and thinking of a solution when the ID is not given, and
would like to just get a list based on the AttributeID only.

Any tips would help greatly!

thanks!

Comment: It's Oracle - let me update my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this help?

```
select * from attributes a
where attribute_id := given_attribute_id
and version_id = (
 select max( version_id ) from attributes b
where attribute_id := given_attibute_id 
and b.id = a.id 

)
```

Comment: this is what I have initially -- yes it would work but it requires me to input a given_id

Comment: @aggie - I don't understand what you mean by "it requires me to input a given_id". Your example in the question indicates this is what you need to do?

Comment: @Martin, the "id" is not necessary part of the query.

Comment: the above solution doesn't require you to provide the "id". It will give result for all IDs for the given Attribute_id (with the latest version).

Comment: Ah I see. You were both talking about `id` and for some reason I was thinking you were talking about `AttrId`

Comment: +1 yes - this solution is equally good and less complex !! thanks for the help !!

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT ID,
                AttributeID,
                AttributeValue,
                Version,
                row_number() over (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY version DESC) AS rn
         FROM   your_table
         WHERE AttributeID=1)
SELECT ID,
       AttributeID,
       AttributeValue,
       Version
FROM   T
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Comment: Hmm, Not sure I understand the relevance of the attributeid though.

Comment: in this case ... my object has several different attributes and each attribute has a version attached to it and i am trying to query the latest version of a given attribute in an obj.

Comment: Yes it was the comment on the other answer that threw me a bit. I think this should do what you need.

Comment: Looks like it works! - thanks for the help - but I probably need to understand the partition keyword so that i can explain my code. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
Select ...
From EAV
Where AttributeId = @AttributeId
    And Version =   (
                    Select Max( E1.Version )
                    From EAV As E1
                    Where E1.Id = EAV.Id
                        And E1.AttributeId = EAV.AttributeId
                    )
```